State update creates infinite loop
Why does assigning the setTimeSlotsList(fetchAPI(day)) create an infinite loop?
The code flow seems to be working when I just console.log(fetchAPI(day)) for testing.
const [timeSlotsList, setTimeSlotsList] = useState([])

function FormValues () {
  const { values } = useFormikContext();
  const day = new Date(values.date)

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeSlotsList(fetchAPI(day))
  }, [values.date]);
}

const AvailableTimes = (props) => {
  const timeSlots = props.data.map(time =>
    <option value={time}>{time}</option>
  )
  return (
    <>{timeSlots}</>
  )
}

function updateTime (valueTime) {
  return (
    setTimeSlotsList(
      timeSlotsList.filter(a => a !== valueTime)
    )
  )
}

The fetchAPI function is shown below:
const seededRandom = function (seed) {
  var m = 2**35 - 31;
  var a = 185852;
  var s = seed % m;
  return function () {
    return (s = s * a % m) / m;
  };
}

const fetchAPI = function(date) {
  let result = [];
  let random = seededRandom(date.getDate());

  for (let i = 17; i <= 23; i++) {
    if (random() < 0.5) {
      result.push(i + ':00');
    }
    if (random() < 0.5) {
      result.push(i + ':30');
    }
  }
  return result;
};


What is values.date? Is it a primitive type or a reference type?

Could you add all the pieces of the puzzle at once? I'm not quite sure why you're adding them piece by piece. Where's the code for setTimeSlotsList, and also for the context?

its an Reference data type. 'values.date' is the value obtained from the Input with type='date'.

@Armen I have edited the code above to show the full picture

Thanks. Are you using useState outside of a component, or is it a typo?

@Armen const [timeSlotsList, setTimeSlotsList] = useState ([]) is declared within the main component. outside of inner functions like fetchAPI....

It seems you haven't provided all the code. Please provide the complete part so that I can copy and run it. Without the full code, I won’t be able to give the correct answer.

@Armen i tried but it wont allow me to paste all the code here. it says its too long.

Maybe you could use a codebox or another tool to share it more effectively.

Rarely do we need that mutch code to answer a question. A good way to find the problem is by creating a copy (fork or branch) of your project. Then remove all the bloat that is not relevant to the issue. See if you can find the minimum amount of code needed to produce the issue. In quite a number of cases you'll solve your own issue by doing this. If you still don't know what the issue is after reducing the code, the minimum amount of code should fit inside a Stack Overflow question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Please [edit] to include a complete and comprehensible [mcve] so readers here can see and understand what your does and when it does it. If there are errors, please include the complete error message and any accompanying stacktrace(s) and any specific reproduction steps to produce the issue if they are necessary to understanding the proble.

I was able to resolve this by creating another useEffect call outside of the FormValues function which is causing the re-render that leads to infinite loop.

I was able to resolve this by creating another useEffect call outside of the FormValues function which is causing the re-render that leads to infinite loop.
  useEffect(() => {
    const day = new Date(dateSelected)
        setTimeSlotsList(fetchAPI(day))
  }, [dateSelected]);
  
  const FormValues = () => {
    const { values } = useFormikContext();

      useEffect(() => {
        setDateSelected(values.date)
      }, [values.date]);
  }


I am using Formik building this form which makes a bit complicated.

The useEffect hook in React is designed to run its callback function whenever one of the dependencies in the dependency array changes.Here values.date is the dependency. So each time this changes useEffect runs. The effect runs when values.date changes, which triggers setTimeSlotsList(fetchAPI(day)).
If fetchAPI(day) somehow triggers a change in values.date, a new render is triggered, and the useEffect runs again because values.date is a new object/reference. This creates a loop because values.date changes on every render.

from what I can see, the fetchAPI function doesn't seem to trigger any changes to the dependency of the useEffect hook. I have updated the questions above to show the fetchAPI function
